# Triggered Send Delivery Profile Error

Tags: email

I have an issue with Triggered Sends.

In order to get rid of the standard header and footer I override the Delivery Profile with a custom one. To this profile I have attached my own header and footer, created with the content editor. However, when I want to save these profile changes to the Triggered Send I see this:

[image]

This seems to be related to removing the header and footer. As soon as I use the default Delivery Profile (with the default header and footer), there is no problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add personalized strings, minimum required:

```
%%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%,
%%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
```

Update Your Profile:

```
%%profile_center_url%%
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bypass the error checking by embedded the codes above by using something like: . for each. However, there's a reason those error checks are in place - they're to keep people from running afoul of CAN-SPAM and spam filters from the ESP's, so do so after careful consideration.